# Oracle: multiple rows in INTO variable in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My procedure look like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_TMS_OPT_DATA
AS

V_NAME           VARCHAR2(10);
V_TEL_NO         VARCHAR2(10);
V_ADDR           VARCHAR2(10);
...

SELECT NEW_NAME
     , NEW_TEL_NO
     , NEW_ADDR
     , REG_NO
  INTO V_NAME     -- get data row. but it is error.
     , V_TEL_NO
     , V_ADDR  
     , V_REG_NO
  FROM DAILY_VISITOR;
  
  MERGE  -- I use MERGE, because INSERT or UPDATE
  INTO ALL_VISITOR A
  USING dual
    ON (A.REG_NO = V_REG_NO)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE
          SET A.ADDR = V_ADDR
            , A.NAME = V_NAME
            , A.TEL_NO = V_TEL_NO
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (REG_NO, NAME, TEL_NO, ADDR)
       VALUES (V_REG_NO, V_NAME, V_TEL_NO, V_ADDR);

...
```

I get data in `DAILY_VISITOR` and insert or update in `ALL_VISITOR`.

But I get an error

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

How can I get multiple rows of data using `INTO` or other?

Or is it possible use `MERGE` like `INSERT INTO SELECT`?

Oracle is 11g.

Comment: A `SELECT INTO` in PL/SQL must return exactly one and only one result. Either 0 results or more than 1 result will throw an error. If you need multiple rows, don't use `SELECT INTO`. Either don't use PL/SQL at all, or use a cursor loop to act on each row individually, or `BULK COLLECT INTO` into a collection and use that either in a loop or as a table source in SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To `SELECT` multiple rows into variables you can either use:

- `BULK COLLECT INTO` with collection variables; or
- open the statement as a cursor and use row-by-row processing with the cursor.

But don't do either of those two because you should not be using intermediate variables for this problem and should not be using PL/SQL; instead, combine the two statements and solve it entirely in SQL:

```sql
MERGE INTO ALL_VISITOR A
USING (
  SELECT NEW_NAME
       , NEW_TEL_NO
       , NEW_ADDR
       , REG_NO
  FROM DAILY_VISITOR
) v
ON (A.REG_NO = V.REG_NO)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET A.ADDR = V.NEW_ADDR
    , A.NAME = V.NEW_NAME
    , A.TEL_NO = V.NEW_TEL_NO
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (REG_NO, NAME, TEL_NO, ADDR)
  VALUES (V.REG_NO, V.NEW_NAME, V.NEW_TEL_NO, V.NEW_ADDR);
```